# How to highlight current menu bar base on the URL?

Tags: theme-development, menus, css

```
==================================
Home Contact About
==================================
```

For example, The menu should looks like

```
==================================
Home Contact About
     -------
==================================
```

when the URL is http://loaclhost/contact/XXXXXXXX, the same as other.

How to do this? It seems can use `nav_menu_css_class` by add_filter, but the key is how to judgment the current menu is contact (or other)?

Comment: I have found the perfect solution. If anybody has the same issue, please go to http://www.rarescosma.com/2010/11/add-a-class-to-wp_nav_menu-items-with-urls-included-in-the-current-url/

Answer (score 1):

If you're using WordPress custom menus ( and you should when you're dealing with menus ), it adds class `current-menu-item` for page that is currently being viewed.

Comment: Thanks answer. I just found a perfect solution about it. For sharing. http://www.rarescosma.com/2010/11/add-a-class-to-wp_nav_menu-items-with-urls-included-in-the-current-url/